# Is it possible to define a stream with a payload field that accepts an array of values?

Tags: wso2

My scenario is as follows:

- WSO2BAM 2.4.0 will be used to present KPIs from data captured from WSO2ESB proxies
- One of the operations of a given proxy takes an array of items, each one with some fields
- One of the KPIs requires that I do some aggregate calculations over all items of all messages

A possible solution would be to send multiple events to BAM using an iterator, but this seems a bit inefficient to me. A cleaner approach would be a way to specify that a given payload field can accept an array of values.

I've read the library examples, but they only cover simple streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to define a payload(or any other) field that accepts an array of values for a stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe in the future the bam mediator could  take an OMElement as input.

Comment: Hi Phillipe, Do you mean an OMElement that has fields with multiple values (arrays)? You can send XML as string via the BAM mediator if you want even now. But there will have to be some logic to break it down properly at BAM side which is not available out of the box currently. The BAM mediator uses Thrift as its transport and currently uses a pre-defined format. Yes, maybe the BAM mediator can be improved to send customizable XML formats in the future. You can start up a discussion at architecture mailing list of WSO2 regarding this... :-)